# Converting every other string element in a CSringArray into an int - MFC C++

Tags: c++, arrays, mfc

i know how to convert a CString into an int, i can just use atoi or wtoi, but in this case the string is inside an array.

In my case i'm creating a calculator where the user inputs their equation which gets stored as a string. I then used a tokenizer to move each number and operator into an array. After that i want to change only the numbers into ints so that i can start getting the answer for the inputs.

I have something like this:

`CStringArray arr = ['1','+','32','-','5']`

**my question is how do i turn the numbers that are strings into ints in the array?**

i read around online where people said to subtract by '0', so i tried:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.GetSize(); i+2)
 {
    arr[i] = arr[i] - _T('0');  
 }
```

but I'm not sure how to check because there's no command line in visual studio MFC

Comment: The substract '0' trick is for converting a character into an integer.

Comment: It's hard to see the real question, could you state your question more clear ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `atoi(str)` on a `CString` then just use `atoi(arr[i])` on a `CStringArray`.

That's really very basic, maybe you are asking a different question.

Comment: Also, assignment must be done to some variable of type `int` or type casting to `int` just before usage of converted array elements.

Comment: @Aleksei that's where i'm confused, if my array was super long and had x amount of numbers, does that mean i would need x amount of variables of type int?

Comment: @khoi, it depends on the algorithm you are using for processing of the array. One algorithm converts all the symbolic representation of integers into array of them and then do the calculation. Another - converts to integer each string and do calculation on the fly, storing partial result in one variable and use it as the input for another operations in the formula being parsed.

Comment: @khoi You need a second array of `int`s of the same size as your array of strings to store the results of each call to `atoi(arr[i])`.

Comment: @acraig5075 would something like this work? `arr2[i] = atoi(arr[i])`. Does that copy the values over?

Comment: @khoi Yes that's right, perfect for the numeric values, you'll get 0's for the non-numeric chars like '+' and '-'.

Answer (score 0):

As @john mentioned in his answer, you can try something like this:

```
int j=0;
for(int i = 0; i < arr.GetSize(); i+=2)// use i+=2 instead of i+2
 {
    arr2[j++] = atoi(arr[i]);// value of j->0,1,2.. whereas i->0,2,4,..  
 }
```

Here `arr2` is integer array.
**EDIT:**
if you want to perform operation like `int Ans = arr2[i-1] + arr2[i+1];` then no need of second array.
You can use same array.

```
int Ans;
for(int i = 0; i < arr.GetSize(); i++)
{
    if(arr[i] == _T("+"))// or any operator sign
         Ans =  atoi(arr[i-1]) + atoi(arr[i+1]);
}
```

Or

```
int Ans = atoi(arr[0]);
for(int i = 1; i < arr.GetSize(); i+2)
{
    switch(arr[i])
    {
     case '+':
        Ans = Ans + atoi(arr[i+1]);// at the end result will save in 'Ans'
        break;
     case '-':
        Ans = Ans - atoi(arr[i+1]);
        break;
    //.........Other cases
    //........
    }
}
```

Comment: oh ok, i get it. but what do i do about the operators? because arr2 is now only `arr2=[1,2,4,5,6,7,etc...]` i was originally thinking of doing this:
 for(int i = 1; i < arr.GetSize(); i+=2)
 {
  if(arr2[i] == _T("+")) // or '- * /' i will make this a function after
  {
   intAns = arr2[i-1] + arr2[i+1]; 
  }
 }

Comment: sorry im new at this, idk how to make it look like a block of code.

Comment: for the second method you showed, im getting "error C2450: switch expression of type 'CString' is illegal"

Comment: @khoi, Actually `CStringArray` will return `CString`, you can try `switch(arr[i][0])`. it will give you char value.

Comment: it didnt seem to work for me, so i just made it into if statements, and now it works perfectly. thanks!